# EF code first: InvalidOperationException The multiplicity constraint is violated

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

When I try load all my CssFile from my repositories, I get an multiplicity error. When debugging the current  existing objects, everything seems to be fine. I've tried to Include() the page but same error occurred.

```
    public CssFile FindByPage(Page page)
    {
        return cssFiles.Where(f => f.PageId == page.Id).Single();
    }
```

> The multiplicity constraint is violated. The role of the relationship
>   Page_CssFile_Target Paycento_Models.DAL.Page_CssFile, the multiplicity
>   1 or 0 .. 1.

```
 public class Page
    {
        [Key()]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CssFile")]
        public int CssFileId { get; set; }
        public virtual CssFile CssFile { get; set; }
     }

  public class CssFile
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
         [Key()]
        [ForeignKey("Page")]
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code should be

```
public class Page
{
    [Key()]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("CssFile")]
    //public int CssFileId { get; set; }
    public virtual CssFile CssFile { get; set; }
 }

public class CssFile
{
    [Key()]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
  }
```

There's no need for 'PageId' in CssFile, since the relationship is one-to-one and the primary keys will be shared.

Answer (score 0):

It had something to do with the Lazy loading and I was trying to reload objects which were already loaded. Don't know the specifics of why it crashed though but managed to fix it.